# Не отрабатывает событие

Tags: php, битрикс

Использую данный метод, для исключения из результатов поиска детального описания и анонса : https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/17138/blog/6662/ ,но ничего не меняется, в init.php:

```
AddEventHandler("search", "BeforeIndex", "BeforeIndexHandler"); 
function BeforeIndexHandler($arFields) {

   $arrIblock = array(4);   //ID инфоблоков, для которых производить модификацию    
   $arDelFields = array("DETAIL_TEXT","PREVIEW_TEXT");    //стандартные поля, которые нужно исключить    
       if (CModule::IncludeModule('iblock') && $arFields["MODULE_ID"] == 'iblock' && in_array($arFields["PARAM2"], $arrIblock) && intval($arFields["ITEM_ID"]) > 0){
          $dbElement = CIblockElement::GetByID($arFields["ITEM_ID"]);
          if ($arElement = $dbElement->Fetch()){
             foreach ($arDelFields as $value) {
                if (isset ($arElement[$value]) && strlen($arElement[$value])> 0){        
                   $arFields["BODY"] = str_replace(CSearch::KillTags($arElement[$value]), "", $arFields["BODY"]);       
                }          
             }             
          }          
            //$arFields = array();  
          return $arFields;       
       } 
   }
```

Похоже, что не отрабатывает событие. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Попробуйте так `AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserAdd", Array("MyClass", "OnAfterUserAddHandler"));` на примере [этого](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onafteruseradd.php)

Comment: Так тоже не работает..Может модуль нужно дополнительно подключать? Хоть убей не пойму почему не работает!

Comment: если все делаете как [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/search/events/beforeindex.php) то пишите в поддержку